# Set gradient backgroundcolor from colorpicker with jquery?

Tags: jquery, colors

I want to beable to select 2 colors and display a div with a gradient background!

I have 2 colorpickers done with "jscolor.com" where I can select colors and the color I choose gets displayed in an input field.

```
Top color<br />
<input type="text" name="color1" class="colors" size="7" value="#444444"/>
<br><br>
Bottom color<br />
<input type="text" name="color2" class="colors" size="7" value="#17181a"/>
```

and then the div where I would like to display a gradient background.

```
<div id="gradient"></div>
```

How can I set the background color based on the input fields?
And suggestions appriciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps:

- give inputs unique IDs so you can retrieve them easily.
- use jQuery's `.css()` to set `background-image: linear-gradient...` and don't forget to include all vendor prefixes.
- refresh `linear-gradient` when input changes and when page is loaded

**Example:**

```
$(function() {
  // when inputs change, update the gradient
  $(".color").change(refreshGradient);
  // draw the gradient when page is loaded
  refreshGradient();
});

function refreshGradient() {
  var gradientBody = 'linear-gradient(top, ' + $("#color1").val() + ', ' + $("#color2").val() + ')';

  // we need to use vendor prefixes
  $.each(['', '-o-', '-moz-', '-webkit-', '-ms-'], function() {
    $("#gradient").css({ 'background-image': this + gradientBody });
  });
}
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/awivoq/3/edit#javascript,live)** is the code.

**Update:** (see comments)

To integrate the with jQuery minicolors `.change()` handler must be registered differently:

```
$(".color").miniColors({
  change: refreshGradient
});
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/awivoq/4/edit#javascript,live)** is the example using [jQuery miniColors](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/02/jquery-minicolors-a-color-selector-for-input-controls/) plugin.

Comment: Hi dzejkej and thanks a lot.
I have tryed it but I cant get it to work, I first had to change the colorpicker to minicolors instead(http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/02/jquery-minicolors-a-color-selector-for-input-controls/) because the page that I have the colorpicker in is loaded with ajax and tested the jscolor picker on a seperate page and when I used it in the ajax page it is not working. So I found the minicolor one instead and that works in my page, but I cant get your code to work with that picker? Ill post my code below.

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson I updated my answer with a code change and working example - please have a look and don't forget to upvote and accept the answer :). Also you should update your question instead of writing an answer.Please edit you question and add the text from the answer there and delete your answer.

Comment: dzejkel!!!You are the man :-) Thank you verry much!
I had to remove 
$(document).ready( function() {                         
$(".color").miniColors({                                    
});
to make it work. But now it work perfect!
Thanks a lot!